# prevent running two function instances simultaneously in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using a rest interface to do a process that can take some time, once the process gets started, another instance should not be able to start and just return a notification that such process is under way.

Is there a way to watch for this process being executed (running state) without using a lock (file or db)?

Comment: Sure, the long running process is probably done with a function that has a callback or returns a promise, and then all you'll need is a recursive function, but without any code it's hard to write an example.

Comment: Are you talking about separate node processes? If not, a simple flag variable will do as a lock (but you can't do it without one)

Comment: There's insufficient description of your setup to understand how to answer this.  If your own code is responsible for starting the child process, you can just monitor the child process directly after you start it and have other code check if there is already one running.  If it's something outside your node.js process that starts it, you can use various OS tools to check the process list for a particular process signature that is currently running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this would work

```
var isRunning = false;

function doStuff(){
    if(isRunning){
        return 'this function is already running';
    }

    isRunning = true;
    // do things with a promise or whatever.then(function(){
        isRunning = false;
    })
}
```

Comment: I think I've over-thought the problem at hand.